# How to go from these horizontally stacked flex items to vertically stacked flex items?

Tags: css, flexbox

The following code stacks flex items horizontally:

```css
.col-12 {
  display: flex
}

input {
  flex: 0 0 80%
}

label {
  flex: 0 0 20%
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" value=""></input>
</div>
```

[image]

What should I change so `Message` is on top of the input field? (And the input field fills the whole container?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="col-12">
  <label>Label</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" value=""></input>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-12 {
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
}
```